# Drools : 2 identical calls to the same knowledgeBase don't give the same result... why?

Tags: drools, stateless

I am using drools to process some user rules (the Excel way).
If I call the rules with the exact same data at different time in the process, I don't get the same result. (I am using a StateLessSession)

Can someone explain me why ?

Here is more info on how I use it :
The **Excel rule** is something like

```
    | CONDITION | CONDITION | ACTIVATION-GROUP | ACTION              |
    |  myFact : MyFact                         | myFact              |
    |  isOK     | isBuild   |                  | setStatus("$param") |
     -----------------------------------------------------------------
    |  true     |           |    firstmatch    |   DONE              |
    |           |   true    |    firstmatch    |   TODO              |
```

**Declaration with Spring** :

```
    <drools-spring:kbase id="kbase"> 
      <drools-spring:resources>
        <drools-spring:resource type="DTABLE" source="classpath:rules/myRule.xls" >
          <drools-spring:decisiontable-conf input-type="XLS" worksheet-name="processStatus"/>
        </drools-spring:resource>
      </drools-spring:resources>
    </drools-spring:kbase>

    <drools-spring:ksession id="ksession" type="stateless" kbase="kbase" />
```

Use in **the code** :

```
    ksession.addEventListener(new DebugAgendaEventListener() );
    ksession.addEventListener(new DebugWorkingMemoryEventListener());
    ksession.execute(myFact);
```

**The log** (with the event listener) when I call it at first

```
    ==>[ActivationCreatedEvent: getActivation()=[Activation rule=process status_14, act#=0, salience=65522, tuple=[fact 0:2:1494868136:199421486:2:DEFAULT:MyFact(...<identical data>..., status=NONE)]], getKnowledgeRuntime()=org.drools.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl@5febd2b9]
    ==>[ObjectInsertedEventImpl: getFactHandle()=[fact 0:2:1494868136:199421486:2:DEFAULT:MyFact(...<identical data>..., status=NONE)], getObject()=MyFact(...<identical data>..., status=NONE), getKnowledgeRuntime()=org.drools.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl@5febd2b9, getPropagationContext()=PropagationContextImpl [activeActivations=0, dormantActivations=0, entryPoint=EntryPoint::DEFAULT, factHandle=[fact 0:2:1494868136:199421486:2:DEFAULT:MyFact(...<identical data>..., status=NONE)], leftTuple=null, originOffset=-1, propagationNumber=2, rule=null, type=0]]
    ==>[BeforeActivationFiredEvent:  getActivation()=[Activation rule=process status_14, act#=0, salience=65522, tuple=[fact 0:2:1494868136:199421486:2:DEFAULT:MyFact(...<identical data>..., status=NONE)]], getKnowledgeRuntime()=org.drools.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl@5febd2b9]
    ==>[AfterActivationFiredEvent: getActivation()=[Activation rule==process status_14, act#=0, salience=65522, tuple=[fact 0:2:1494868136:199421486:2:DEFAULT:MyFact(...<identical data>..., status=DONE)]], getKnowledgeRuntime()=org.drools.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl@5febd2b9]
```

As you can read, after this call, the status on myFact change to "DONE"

Now, after others calls to this rule with completely different data (about 20 calls), here is **the log** of the call with the same data as above :

```
    ==>[ObjectInsertedEventImpl: getFactHandle()=[fact 0:2:1929411279:-1926420662:2:DEFAULT:MyFact(...<identical data>..., status=NONE)], getObject()=MyFact(...<identical data>..., status=NONE)), getKnowledgeRuntime()=org.drools.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl@5febd2b9, getPropagationContext()=PropagationContextImpl [activeActivations=0, dormantActivations=0, entryPoint=EntryPoint::DEFAULT, factHandle=[fact 0:2:1929411279:-1926420662:2:DEFAULT:MyFact(...<identical data>..., status=NONE)], leftTuple=null, originOffset=-1, propagationNumber=2, rule=null, type=0]]
```

And that's it : no rule activated...

any Guess ? is it because of the "ACTIVATION-GROUP" ? if so why.. it is supposed to be stateless ?

Thanks for all your ideas !

Comment: Here's not the right place to discuss debugging. Need a small but complet set of all the code to reproduce the issue, especially the DRL produced by that spreadsheet, Drools version,... Can you post details on the Drools user list?

Comment: OK, do you mean that might be a bug within drools ? Anyway, I ll try to post this on the Drools user list tomorrow, but I won't be able to give more code since it is as simple as I wrote in the post. I will also generate the DRL files(Drools version is 5.5.0.Final)

Comment: As long as the problem can be reproduced. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer : I got hard time to make it reproducible and simple. Anyway, I posted the problem on the drools user list : http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/Drools-2-identical-calls-to-the-same-knowledgeBase-don-t-give-the-same-result-why-td4028038.html and sources can be found here :http://www.filedropper.com/using-drools Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug of the 5.5.0.Final version.
If I upgrade the project to 5.6.0.FINAL, it works !

This was answered on the drools user list : http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/Drools-2-identical-calls-to-the-same-knowledgeBase-don-t-give-the-same-result-why-td4028038.html